# Notice: Undefined index: m in

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined index: m in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3

```
<?
$m = $_REQUEST["m"];
$uname = $_REQUEST["uname"];
if($m=="chkfrm"){   //Check about true values
    if($uname==""){ //if input form 'uname' is null
?>
No content


<?
    } else { // Else input form 'uname' is value
    //$m="";    // Reset chkfrm
?>
In Content


<? }
} else { //Main page
?>


<form name="aa" method="post" action="./test.php">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="chkfrm">
<input type="text" name="uname" size="30">
<p>
<input type="image" src="./jigoku/images/name.gif" class="mouse" onClick="javascript:returns();">
</p>
</form>
<?
}   //Main End
?>
```

Comment: Please do a Google search or a local search in SO before asking a question

Comment: You need also to understand the life cycle of a page with a form on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` when assigning the variable.

```
$m = isset($_REQUEST['m']) ? $_REQUEST['m'] : null;
```

Comment: Thank you Your answer was helpful

Comment: With PHP 7.* you can also do:
$m = $_REQUEST['m'] ?? null;